# Aurelia dialog is shown more than once

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-dialog

When opening a dialog, it is shown more than once

Tried to prevent double opening by checking if a dialog is already open

```
if (!this.dialogService.hasOpenDialog) {
  return this.dialogService
    .open({ viewModel: AssignTeam })
    .whenClosed((response) => {
      if (!response.wasCancelled) {
        return this.protectionService.assignTeam(devices, response.output);
      }

      this.selectedDevices.splice(0);
    });
}
```

Expected: One dialog should be shown. When the user clicks ok it should be gone
Actual: The dialog is opened more than once. When the user clicks ok, he is presented by the same dialog and has to cancel it

Here is the html when opening the dialog:

```html
<body class="ux-dialog-open">
    <ux-dialog-overlay style="z-index: 1000;" class="active"></ux-dialog-overlay>
    <ux-dialog-container style="z-index: 1000;" class="active">
        <div style="margin-top: 84.5px; margin-bottom: 84.5px;">
            <div>
                <div class="popup">
                    <div class="black-bg1">
                        <ai-dialog class="modalpopup-container padd35 dis-block">
                            <ai-dialog-header>
                                <!-- omitted --> 
                            </ai-dialog-header>
                            <ai-dialog-body>
                                <!-- ommited-->
                            </ai-dialog-body>
                            <ai-dialog-footer class="text-center">
                                <!-- ommitted-->
                            </ai-dialog-footer>
                        </ai-dialog>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ux-dialog-container>
    <ux-dialog-overlay style="z-index: 1000;" class="active"></ux-dialog-overlay>
    <ux-dialog-container style="z-index: 1000;" class="active">
        <div style="margin-top: 84.5px; margin-bottom: 84.5px;">
            <div>
                <div class="popup">
                    <div class="black-bg1">
                        <ai-dialog class="modalpopup-container padd35 dis-block">
                            <ai-dialog-header>
                                <!-- omitted-->
                            </ai-dialog-header>
                            <ai-dialog-body>
                               <!-- omitted-->
                            </ai-dialog-body>
                            <ai-dialog-footer class="text-center">
                                <!-- omitted-->
                            </ai-dialog-footer>
                        </ai-dialog>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ux-dialog-container>
    <script id="__bs_script__">
        //<![CDATA[
        document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.3'><\/script>".replace("HOST",
            location.hostname));
        //]]>
    </script>
    <script async="" src="/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.26.3"></script>
    <div aurelia-app="main" class="page_container">
        <!-- omitted-->
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        requirejs.config({
            skipDataMain: true
        });
        // Configure Bluebird Promises.
        Promise.config({
            longStackTraces: false,
            warnings: false,
            cancellation: true
        });
        require(['aurelia-bootstrapper']);
    </script>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Also tried to investigate more, using this code:

```
if (!this.dialogService.hasActiveDialog) {
  console.log(this.dialogService);

  return this.dialogService
    .open({ viewModel: AssignTeam })
    .then((openDialogResult: DialogOpenResult) => {
      console.log(openDialogResult);
      return openDialogResult.closeResult;
    });
```

[DialogService debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woz8J.png)

It seems like two controllers are allocated

Comment: I have found the issue. While the dialog was being opened, an event occurred which opened the dialog which also opened a dialog.

Comment: you should write that as an answer so the question can be closed.